# Why is VSCode is asking to receive keystrokes from any application?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode out of no where asked to receive keystrokes from any application. [Permission that came up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVJJ8.png)

Is this some sort of malware in vscode?

I denied it for now but I would like to report it and tell others that it happened.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399731/meaning-of-applications-would-like-to-receive-keystrokes-from-any-application

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same after restarting VSCode with the latest version

```
Version: 1.83.1
Commit: f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc
Date: 2023-10-10T23:46:55.789Z
Electron: 25.8.4
ElectronBuildId: 24154031
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 22.6.0
```

P.S. Somebody else is reported it too - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/189429